# Arcgis IPolygon(System.__comObject) and ILine2 (Esri.Arcgis.LineClass) intersection

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

Currently I am developing a Server Object Extension. On my project I am creating a new line class with 
`LineClass myLine = new LineClass();`
and getting a polygon from client as JsonObject than converting this polygon to IPolygon with

```
JsonObject jsonFieldPolygon;
if (!operationInput.TryGetJsonObject("field", out jsonFieldPolygon))
     throw new ArgumentNullException("field");
IPolygon4 fieldGeom = (IPolygon4)Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonFieldPolygon,esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon);
```

Polygon I have converted from jsonobject is becoming a COM object, but line I have created is a class in my own application space.

Thus I can't do operations with these two geometries, I guess both must be COM object for operations like intersect and etc.

I am getting an access violation when I try to intersect these two geometries.

My code is below:

```
JsonObject jsonFieldPolygon;
if (!operationInput.TryGetJsonObject("field", out jsonFieldPolygon))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("field");
IPolygon4 fieldGeom = (IPolygon4)Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonFieldPolygon, esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon);

JsonObject jsonFieldPath;
if (!operationInput.TryGetJsonObject("fieldPath", out jsonFieldPath))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("fieldPath");
IPolyline fieldPathGeom = (IPolyline)Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonFieldPath, esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline);

ITopologicalOperator myOp = (ITopologicalOperator)fieldGeom;

IGeometry resultGeom = myOp.Intersect(fieldPathGeom, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry1Dimension); // this line works because both geometries are com objects


IPoint startPoint = new PointClass();
IPoint endPoint = new PointClass();
LineClass myLine = new LineClass();

myLine.SpatialReference = fieldGeom.SpatialReference;
endPoint.SetEmpty();
startPoint.SetEmpty();

startPoint.PutCoords(fieldGeom.Envelope.XMin, fieldGeom.Envelope.YMin);
endPoint.PutCoords(fieldGeom.Envelope.XMax, fieldGeom.Envelope.YMax);

myLine.PutCoords(startPoint, endPoint);

IGeometry resultGeom2 = myOp.Intersect(myLine, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry1Dimension);// this line throws accessviolation exception because one geometry is com other is a class in my app
```

I hope there is a way to solve this

Comment: i guess i need to use a function like ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ArcGISServer.Converter.ComObjectToValueObject, but i dont have and use adf on my soe, any ideas or similar function for soe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the geometry objects you have created (either by deserializing from JSON or instantiating them with `new`) are COM objects and are created in the same process space.

Your issue probably stems from the fact that the [ITopologicalOperator.Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Intersect_Method/002m000003vs000000/) method works only on high-level geometries 
(see the Remarks section in the link). `Line` is not a high-level geometry, whereas `Polyline` is, that's why your first call of `Intersect` works and the other does not. You will need to represent your line with a `Polyline` instance instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, i was banging my head to walls because of this